# Return data from void-visitor without changing the abstract visitor

Tags: java, oop, factory, visitor-pattern, abstract-factory

I am using a Java framework that provides some kind of visitor pattern for processing elements. There is an abstract super class `AbstractProcessor<T>` (which I cannot change) that provides a method `public abstract void process(T visitedElement)`.

I then have defined several concrete implementations of such processors and instantiate them by Factory Pattern to then use them via their common supertype. Now, how do I get any type of information out of there? I obviously cannot simply return something, since the abstract process-method is of type void.

My only thought so far would be something like a data-field I can add to the concrete implementation (since I cannot change the abstract super class), so to do smth like this:

```
public class MyProcessor extends AbstractProcessor<SomeType> {
public String data;

  @Override
  public void process(SomeType t) {
  [do stuff...]
  this.data = "some important info";
  }
}
```

But to receive this data from - lets say a list of their common super types that do not posess the data-field - I would have to do some ugly type checking and casting like this:

```
List<AbstractProcessor> list = getProcessors();
list.forEach(p -> {
  someType.processWith(p); //someType accepts AbstractProcessor's and then runs their process-method
  if(p instanceOf MyProcessor) 
    System.out.println( ((MyProcessor)p).data );
  }
});
```

Is there any other way to retrieve some type of data that gets calculated during the `process` method this way?

Comment: Create an abstract WithResultProcessor, which extends AbstractProcessor, and defined an additional getResult() method. Then create a List<WithResultProcessor>, and call getResult on each processor after it has been passed to `processWith()`?

Comment: Yeah, I also got to think of that possibility and as of now I see it as the best solution! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have an intrinsically unsolvable problem here. I understand you're saying:

- You've written several `AbstractProcessor` subclasses.
- They all do different things and produce different results.
- You want to treat them all homogeneously, as instances of `AbstractProcessor`.

But you can't treat them all as instances of the same class, `AbstractProcessor`, if they all produce different results. You have to know what type of processor you have in order to interpret the results.

You have two options. The first option is to unify the results. For example, you could have an interface called `ResultHandler` like this:

```
interface ResultHandler {
   void handleSumResult(int result);
   void handleConcatResult(String result);
   void handleSomeOtherProcessorResult(Whatever result);
}
```

Pass in an instance of `ResultHandler` (either during construction or in a separate `handleResult` method), then (within each processor) invoke the `ResultHandler` method appropriate to that processor type. If you have several different processors that generate sums in some way, at least they can all call the same `handleSumResult` API and you don't have to do `instanceof` anywhere.

The other strategy is to just abandon your attempt to treat all processors homogeneously. I think this might be the better option. Your code obviously knows what processor it needs to use, so just go ahead and instantiate that one, use it, and collect the results from whatever API you define. If there's some reason why you have to treat the processors homogeneously (e.g., the processor class is specified by the user, maybe in a configuration file), then move that abstraction up one level and instead have the user specify a class that owns the entire process of processing the data and collecting the results. Instead of specifying `MyProcessor,` the use specifies `MySomethingElse`, and then `MySomethingElse` both instantiates `MyProcessor` and handles the results.

Comment: The concrete processor class actually in deed gets somewhat indirectly defined by the user at runtime, so at development time I need to treat them all the same (that's the reason for the factory pattern). But the last point is the key I think: I just moved the abstraction level one level up and create another abstract Processor that extends AbstractProcessor and contains a data field that I can then access!

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use a field here. Instead: define a suitable interface, like *ResultProcessor* that has a *T getResult()* method. And then have all those subclasses that need to produce a result implement that interface.

Sure, you still have to cast, but at least you can use a generic T to be flexible and your clients can call a method instead of doing direct field access.

Comment: I'm not sure this is an improvement, since in order to determine what T (the result type) is, the OP would still have to do `instanceof` on the processor type (i.e., this is `SumProcessor`, so I know the result is type `int`).

Comment: That was more of a side note. Such details depend on context, the key part is that such an interface is the only real option.

Answer (score 0):

You can make processors "push" data to a hash map for example, which is passed in or accessible globally.

```
public class MyProcessor extends AbstractProcessor<SomeType> {
  public Map<Object, String> data;

  @Override
  public void process(SomeType t) {
  [do stuff...]
  this.data.put(this, "some important info");
  }
}
```

That way the client can have the information which abstract processor added which information, all it needs is access to the map.